# WiFi driver installation fails - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have just installed 16.04 on my Aspire E 15 (E5-573-35Q3)

I have a Qualcom Atheros shown by the following:

```
$ lspci -vvnn
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 50
    Region 0: Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

To install the drivers, I followed the following, as I did with previous disros:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

All runs well except the "make install".  I get gazillion messages like the following:

```
INSTALL /home/cecil/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/compat.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
```

which are repeated for each .ko that it wants to install (123 of them)

Then it says:

```
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.4.0-21-generic
depmod will prefer updates/ over kernel/ -- OK!
Note:
You may or may not need to update your initramfs, you should if
any of the modules installed are part of your initramfs. To add
support for your distribution to do this automatically send a
patch against "update-initramfs.sh". If your distribution does not
require this send a patch with the '/usr/bin/lsb_release -i -s'
("Ubuntu") tag for your distribution to avoid this warning.

Your backported driver modules should be installed now.
Reboot.
```

I then fetch the firmware with:

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

which seems to run fine, but when I reboot - there is still no wifi detected.

Is this a bug in the new distro, or must I do something else?

Thanks

Cecil

I ran `dmesg |grep ath` - got nothing found

I ran `lsmod |grep ath` - got nothing found

I tried to load with `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci`

got the message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Required key not available
```

I tried the `modprobe -r ath10k_pci` just in case, but it did not find it to remove it.

---

OK - I removed the mess that I had made by trying to install a ath10k_pci driver:

```
sudo make uninstall (in the backports.... directory)
```

I then re-booted - lsmod found the drivers now installed:

```
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

`dmesg|grep ath` found a whole lot of info on the firmware I should need.  Would you please translate :-)

```
[   13.180269] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.433624] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   13.433643] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   13.433646] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   13.433657] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[   13.433660] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
[   13.433668] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
[   13.433670] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[   13.433680] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
[   13.433682] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
[   13.433690] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
[   13.433692] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[   13.433695] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[   13.433699] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Thanks

AHA - I think it is fixed.

I see that that the distro did not have QCA9377 drivers.

I then messed things up big time by trying to compile my own.  Once that
mess was undone, then by copying the QCA9377 drivers to /lib/firmware... the system now finds the correct driver and Walllaaaa!

Thanks to chilli555 - the problem is solved!

Comment: I see the L/F did not come out in my paste above, but just squished all the lines together, sorry.  I'll repost if you let me know it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `dmesg | grep ath` Your device is covered by the driver *ath10k_pci* in 16.04 but you are probably missing firmware.

Comment: dmesg |grep ath gives nothing

Comment: However, sudo lspci -vvnn gives more info:

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
 Region 0: Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
 Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
  Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)

Comment: Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
 Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
  Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
  Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
 Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
  DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
   ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
  DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
   RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
   MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
  DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-

Comment: LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
   ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
  LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
   ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
  LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
  DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message
  DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
  LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-

Comment: Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
    Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
  LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
    EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
 Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
  UESta: DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  UEMsk: DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-

Comment: Is the driver `ath10k_pci` loaded? Check: `lsmod` If not, load it: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci` and check again: `dmesg | grep ath`. Please stop posting dozens of lines that I have not requested.

Comment: UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  CESta: RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
  CEMsk: RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
  AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
 Capabilities: [148 v1] Virtual Channel
  Caps: LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
  Arb: Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
  Ctrl: ArbSelect=Fixed
  Status: InProgress-
  VC0: Caps: PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
   Arb: Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-

Comment: Please stop posting what I do not need.

Comment: SORRY - thought they might help.  Apologies.

Comment: sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Required key not available

Comment: If `ath10k_pci` is already loaded as shown in `lsmod`, then unload and reload it: `sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci` and check the message log again: `dmesg | grep ath`. *Edit your question* to add the result. It should tell us what firmware is missing.

Comment: I will propose an answer that will still need more information. Please stand by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error, upon loading the driver, shows the result of a faulty `make` and `sudo make install`:

```
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Required key not available
```

Let's uninstall the driver you built from backports. It is not needed as it already exists in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
cd ~/backports-4.4.2-1
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot and check to see if the default driver is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep ath
```

If so, the message log should show us what firmware is required, if not the firmware you already installed. Check:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

If, in fact, firmware is missing, I will edit this answer to explain how to install it.

Comment: I have just installed 16.04 LTS (kernel 4.4.0-21) so I am sure that my lack of WiFi (can see the SSIDs in network manager, cannot connect to any) is a firmware issue. I still tried to install backports and received the `bss_file.c` error that brought me to this page. Any guidance on how to install appropriate firmware for this? I am using this [device](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/TL-WDN4800.html).

Comment: @tchakravarty Please start your own new question. We'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you @chili555. I have posted my question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/788855/165546).