# Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter + Ubuntu 16.04 woes

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, 16.04, atheros

### NEWS:

- Added update 1
- Added update 2

---

I am trying to build a new machine using the [Gigabyte GA-970 G1 Gaming motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5654),  together with a [TP-Link TL-WDN4800 N900 Wireless Dual Band PCI Express Adapter](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WDN4800.html), which shows up as a Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter in the output of `lspci`. On this machine, I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the `4.4.0-21-generic` kernel.

The issue is that while I can see the SSIDs in the network manager, I cannot connect to any of them.

*Note: While suggesting any solutions, particularly those which involve installing firmware drivers from the internet, note that I do not have internet on the afflicted machine. The onboard ethernet controller is incompatible with Ubuntu as well, and the attempts that I have made to fix that are a whole another story (question!). So, please account for that in your solutions. :-)*

---

## Details:

### Miscellaneous

- Not sure that this is of any consequence, but I have IOMMU <s>disabled</s> **enabled** in my BIOS settings, since without that half of my USB ports do not work.

### lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD990 I/O Memory Management Unit (IOMMU)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1343
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

### lshw

Here is the output of `lshw -C network` -- the driver being used is `ath9k`, version `4.4.0-21-generic`:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 40:8d:5c:e4:ba:a1
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:37 memory:fe300000-fe33ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: ec:08:6b:0c:9c:44
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:fe100000-fe11ffff memory:fe120000-fe12ffff
```

One of the attempts at a fix that I made was to get the backports drivers and install them. I tried installing **from source** the `ath9k`, `alx` & `wifi` from the latest version of backports 4.4.2-1: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz. However, I got the same strange SSL related errors when doing `sudo make install` as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/760610/165546) in every case.

When I inspected the output of `lspci` the driver version had not changed, indicating that the driver installation had not taken.

### lsmod

Here is the output of `lsmod | grep ath`:

```
ath9k                  94208  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              450560  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              643072  1 ath9k
cfg80211              557056  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
compat                 16384  4 cfg80211,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
```

### dmesg

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[   30.338046] ath9k 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   30.418133] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x21
[   30.418135] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   30.418136] ath: Country alpha2 being used: AU
[   30.418137] ath: Regpair used: 0x21
[   30.437260] ath9k 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
[   40.263768] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   40.403766] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   40.479730] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   63.393710] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   63.597081] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   69.573453] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   69.841450] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   77.562014] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   77.701932] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   77.841982] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   77.917988] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00024e00
[   82.602363] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   83.622332] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   84.478301] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   84.682355] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   88.226671] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   90.086726] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   90.162614] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   90.238726] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   94.339002] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[   94.735039] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  120.524670] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  153.298773] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  196.285427] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  196.425522] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  196.629322] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  249.324642] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00020800
[  249.656674] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  375.292183] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  375.432233] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  375.636259] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  438.348003] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  438.487985] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  438.691882] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00020800
[  501.467787] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00004400
[  501.675643] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  564.483630] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  627.751388] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  690.359206] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  690.627214] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  753.366976] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  753.442967] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  753.518694] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  816.434790] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  879.438564] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
[  879.770566] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006400
```

Any pointers as to how to get my wireless adapter working with Ubuntu 16.04 would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

## Update 1:

1. The discussion indicated that the culprit might be the BIOS settings, here are the relevant settings:

   - IOMMU: Enabled
   - XHCI Hand-Off: Enabled
   - EHCI Hand-Off: Enabled
   - Network Stack: Enabled
2. I have also created a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` with the line:

   options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

   since this was a recommendation in [some threads](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237796).
3. There was also some mention in the threads of this being a router security issue, so I have changed two router level parameters as well:

   - WPA Encryption: AES (from TKIP + AES)
   - Group Key Update Interval: 3600 (from 0)

   since this was suggested in [some threads](https://askubuntu.com/a/356192/165546).

---

## Update 2:

As I mentioned in the comments, I acquired a brand new PCI NIC, and when I installed it in the slot that the WiFi adapter was installed, I was still not able to connect to the internet. This then definitely pointed to problems with the board, and so I switched the slot on which I was installing the NIC and the WiFi adapter. So it turns out that I had the WiFi adapter installed in the PCIex1 slot (see image -- yellow box), and when I switched either to the PCIex4 slot (see image -- red box) both the adapters worked perfectly.

[image]

The question then is, is it just this board, or should I not expect to be able to run a WiFi adapter/NIC on a PCIex1 slot? Thanks for all your help, especially @jeremy31 and @chili555.

Comment: Please see post #34 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205970&page=4 In his original question, he had the exact same "DMA failed to stop" errors.

Comment: Go into the backports-4.4.2-1 and run `sudo make uninstall` as the backports are not helping.  The ethernet might work also after following chili555's comment

Comment: @chili555 There are 3 BIOS settings that concern me: IOMMU, xHCI & eHCI. Contrary to what I said in the question, I checked in my BIOS, and IOMMU was enabled, so I tried setting it off, and **none** of my USB ports now work. So if disabling IOMMU is the key, then I am not sure that it will work for me. However, from the thread, the issue was resolved when IOMMU was enabled, so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for the comment. So, just to be clear, my BIOS settings are: IOMMU: Enabled, XHCI Hand-Off: Enabled, EHCI Hand-off: Enabled, and I continue to get the issues above. As I mentioned to chili555, when I disable IOMMU (were it to be the suggested solution), all my USB ports are dead, so that is not a feasible solution.

Comment: @chili555 I am also a little concerned about the country code that I see in the `dmesg` output: `[   30.418136] ath: Country alpha2 being used: AU`. That is categorically not my country code. :-) Would that have anything to do with what is going on?

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with "DMA failed to stop..."; however, you can edit /etc/default/crda to set it. Let me know if you need step-by-step instructions and let us see `dmesg | grep ath` after a reboot.

Comment: @chili555 Happy to try any number of things to get this working, and yes, detailed instructions would be welcome. :-)

Comment: @chili555 I don't think that detailed instructions to edit `/etc/default/crda` will be required. I have just included the line `REGDOMAIN=356`, and will add the result of `dmesg` to the question.

Comment: @chili555 Changing `REGDOMAIN=356` does not change the country alpha2 in the result of `dmesg`.

Comment: I never heard of the country 356!?! JK. It should be a two-letter code from here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 In my case, it is `REGDOMAIN=US`.

Comment: @chili555 I added `REGDOMAIN=IN` and rebooted, but still getting country alpha2 AU. But as you say, maybe that is tangential to this issue.

Comment: I regret that I haven't any further suggestions. Perhaps my colleague @Jeremy31 will jump in.

Comment: Have you uninstalled the backports?  See if the ethernet will function with setting the MTU to 8192, I have a fix for it but it does require internet access.  I would remove the card and try another slot on the motherboard.  I have never seen this behavior from either of my 3 atheros wifi cards

Comment: @Jeremy31 So I caved in (somewhat) and bought a $10 NIC PCI card. So now I have internet. What next? :-)
And no, I did not uninstall backports because I was installing from `/tmp` and lost the build after a reboot. If you think it is critical, I can rebuild and run uninstall.

Comment: No big deal if everything works and the backported drivers will be gone when a new kernel is installed through updates.  Where did you buy the card with the Atheros chip.  It could possibly have been used on a windows pc and had the eeprom programmed with that strange country code

Comment: @Jeremy31 Please see the latest update. My issue is resolved, but there is a question that I have that you might have a ready answer to. Thanks a lot for your help. :-)

Comment: @chili555 Please see the latest update. My issue is resolved but there is a question that I have that you might have a ready answer to. Thanks a lot for your help. :-)

Comment: Sorry; I have no experience with PCIex1 slots and have no suggestions.